# How to get the content of an argument to a Perl subroutine

Tags: perl, function, output, subroutine

I want a sub that takes an argument and prints the argument supplied in its original form along with the evaluation of the argument.

In this case, the evaluation of argument is easy, that's the default! It's getting the actual input in its original form that is difficult.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub echo {
    my ($input) = @_;
    # print "5 + 10 =";
    print $input;
    print "\n";
}

echo 5 + 10;
```

This will output `15`.

I want it to output `5 + 10 = "15"`

Comment: You won't be able to, unless passing '5 + 10' as a string. `5 + 10` is an expression, the result of this expression is what's gets passed into sub; the key is the result doesn't 'remember' anything about how it appeared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sub echo {
    my ($expr, $result) = @_;
    print "$expr = $result\n";
}

echo '5 + 10', 5 + 10;
```

or

```
sub echo {
    my ($expr) = @_;
    my $result = eval($expr);
    die $@ if $@;
    print "$expr = $result\n";
}

echo '5 + 10';
```

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you could do is to pass the string, then evaluate it with `eval`. Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub echo {
    my ($input) = @_;
    print $input, "=";
    print eval $input;
    print "\n";
}

echo "5 + 10";
```

But always be careful with eval: don't use your function with user input.